# Abstract class and implements

Tags: php, abstract, extends

I have a class which contains an abstract method, which is implemented in child class.

```
class A {
  public abstract function foo();
}

class B extends A {
  public function foo() {
      return true;
  }
}
```

How i can get B class's A function value in A class? The classes are in different files and class A already extends from a class

Comment: What do you mean? You can't instantiate an abstract class...Also, looks like you mean "abstract method". For the sake of clarity, can't use use foo(), bar(), baz() and the like? using A() both for class and method gets confusing here

Comment: Where is the `abstract` class that you are mentioning about ?

Comment: You can use something like `function AA(){return $this->A();}` in class `A`. [More detail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

Comment: I meant abstract method.

Answer (score 2):

```
abstract class A {

    abstract public function foo();

    public function bar() {
        echo $this->foo();
    }

}

class B extends A {

    public function foo() {
        return true;
    }

}

$b = new B;
$b->bar();
```